# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database - JDBC - Java EE

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Really odd issue here, it was working a few days ago. I create a new database for a new project and I go to run it and I get the following error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database
```

So I went back to my older projects and tried to run them. Same error.

The database is definitely there, it's named correctly, i'm using user "root". MySQL is started, I can interact with it in terminal... any particular reason I may be getting this error?

```
Connection c =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/twittermap","root","");
```

In terminal:

```
select CURRENT_USER()
```

will return root@localhost

```
SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL;
```

returns twittermap

```
 show variables like 'port';
```

returns 3306

If any more information is required please let me know and I will post it immediately. This is most likely a simple fix but I just can't wrap my head around it. Thanks all, really appreciate the help!

EDIT: I ran netstat -tnl and 127.0.0.1:3306 is NOT listed.. ?

Comment: Run the commands `show databases;`, `use <your database>;`, and `show tables;`.

Comment: show databases lists my database "twittermap" and show tables shows a sole table: "tweet" I also just added a new edit to the original post.

Comment: Is your database running on port 3306?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yep, I just added how I concluded that in the edit. I'm going to try defining the port in the connection. - to no avail

Comment: use `netstat -nap |grep "mysqld"`

Comment: @Gk. I get an error, "netstat: option requires an argument -- p" (I'm on a mac)

Comment: @Dupenheimer okies.. am not aware of MAc OS . just check in the program using ip:port address in connection url let us know

Comment: [Refer this to check listening port](http://juretta.com/log/2007/08/08/list_open_ports_on_your_machine_mac_os_x_/) Also find out there 3306 port is listening

Comment: Hmm. Nowhere in my netstat listings does it say :3306 anywhere. If I grep mysql I get 3 streams, 2 coming out of /tmp/mysql.sock and another coming from XAMPP. (I'm using Eclipse not XAMPP, could this be an issue)?

Comment: So your database is listening to a Unix socket not a TCP socket?

Answer (score -2):

Just write like this:

```
Connection c =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/twittermap","root","");
```

Comment: 3306 is the default, so this doesn't change anything. If the port number was the problem the OP would get a different exception.